# Prevent a function to block

Tags: r, plot

In the package shapes there is a function called

```
estcov
```

that uses some method to give mean of tensors, but this is not the point of the question.
Everytime this function is called appears a plot, i want to stop it plotting without touching the code of the function,there is some trick to do this?
Here there is a riproducible code

```
 S <- array(0,c(5,5,10) )
for (i in 1:10){
tem <- diag(5)+.1*matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
S[,,i]<- tem
}
estcov( S , method="Procrustes")
```

Comment: What package is this function from?

Comment: it is package Shapes

Comment: according to the code of the function (that you can see using `estcov`); you'll always get a plot as long as argument MDKs >=2

Comment: Try `invisible(estcov(...))`, which should suppress any outputs

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to send everything to a `NULL` dev, and close it afterward :

```
pdf(file = NULL)
estcov( S , method="Procrustes")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper around `estcov` that redirects graphics to a temporary file, which is deleted afterwards.

```
estcov_no_plot <- function(...) {
  temp_plot <- tempfile()
  png(temp_plot)
  on.exit({
    dev.off(dev.cur())
    file.remove(temp_plot)
  })
  shapes::estcov(...)
}
```

This example uses a new name for the function to remind you it's not the original. You could name it `estcov`, which would replace the package's function in your environment, but that might cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the part with the plot yourself (commented out below):

```
my_estcov <- function (S, method = "Riemannian", weights = 1, alpha = 1/2,
    MDSk = 2)
{
    out <- list(mean = 0, sd = 0, pco = 0, eig = 0, dist = 0)
    M <- dim(S)[3]
    if (length(weights) == 1) {
        weights <- rep(1, times = M)
    }
    if (method == "Procrustes") {
        dd <- estSS(S, weights)
    }
    if (method == "ProcrustesShape") {
        dd <- estShape(S, weights)
    }
    if (method == "Riemannian") {
        dd <- estLogRiem2(S, weights)

    }
    if (method == "Cholesky") {
        dd <- estCholesky(S, weights)
    }
    if (method == "Power") {
        dd <- estPowerEuclid(S, weights, alpha)
    }
    if (method == "Euclidean") {
        dd <- estEuclid(S, weights)
    }
    if (method == "LogEuclidean") {
        dd <- estLogEuclid(S, weights)
    }
    if (method == "RiemannianLe") {
        dd <- estRiemLe(S, weights)
    }
    out$mean <- dd
    sum <- 0
    for (i in 1:M) {
        sum <- sum + weights[i] * distcov(S[, , i], dd, method = method)^2/sum(weights)
    }
    out$sd <- sqrt(sum)
    dist <- matrix(0, M, M)
 for (i in 2:M) {
        for (j in 1:(i - 1)) {
            dist[i, j] <- distcov(S[, , i], S[, , j], method = method)

            dist[j, i] <- dist[i, j]
        }
    }
    out$dist <- dist
    if (M > MDSk) {
        ans <- cmdscale(dist, k = MDSk, eig = TRUE, add = TRUE,
            x.ret = TRUE)
        out$pco <- ans$points
        out$eig <- ans$eig
        #if (MDSk > 2) {
        #    shapes3d(out$pco[, 1:min(MDSk, 3)], axes3 = TRUE)
        #}
        #if (MDSk == 2) {
        #    plot(out$pco, type = "n", xlab = "MDS1", ylab = "MDS2")
        #    text(out$pco[, 1], out$pco[, 2], 1:length(out$pco[,
        #        1]))
        #}
    }
    out
}
```

You can even add a parameter (a logical `plot = F`) to control when plot or outputs.